# How to fix Error ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved when calling ActiveRecord#find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I am working on a website and whenever someone forgets a null field in the form I get an error saying

```
You cannot call create unless the parent is saved
```

This is the trace:

```
Application Trace
app/views/technicians/offer_comments/_offer_comment.html.slim:1:in `_app_views_technicians_offer_comments__offer_comment_html_slim__1148413763742950523_70319840794240'
app/views/offer_comments/index.html.slim:2:in `_app_views_offer_comments_index_html_slim___917297770217289302_70319839456700'
app/views/shared/offers/_comments.html.slim:8:in `_app_views_shared_offers__comments_html_slim__3779418887197040636_70319839163900'
app/views/technicians/auctions/show.html.slim:98:in `block in _app_views_technicians_auctions_show_html_slim___1454306351028108654_70319829646100'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `rescue in cache'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:6:in `cache'
app/views/technicians/auctions/show.html.slim:1:in `_app_views_technicians_auctions_show_html_slim___1454306351028108654_70319829646100'
app/controllers/technicians/offers_controller.rb:54:in `update'
```

The error appears in the first line of this `html.slim` view:

```
- offer_comment.read_receipts.find_or_create_by user: current_user

.comment id="offer-#{offer_comment.offer_id}-comment-#{offer_comment.id}"
  .by
    - if offer_comment.user == current_user
      = t ".you"
    - else
      = t ".not_you"
    = " - "
    = t '.date', date: time_ago_in_words(offer_comment.created_at)

  .content
    = raw markdown offer_comment.content
```

The interesting part is that this error only occurs when I call another object, `offers`,  in the main view in which the previous code is rendered: `show.html.slim` (last line)

```
ul#customer-auction-tabs.tabs.clean.collapse(data-tabs)
            a#auctions-tabs-chevron href="#" 
              i#auctions-tabs-chevron-icon.fas.fa-chevron-up
            li.tabs-title class=chat_active_class
              a#chat-tab href="#chat" aria-selected="true"= t '.tabs.chat'
            li.tabs-title class=offer_active_class
              a#offers-tab href="#offers"= t '.tabs.offer'
            - if comments_count > 0
              li.tabs-title class=comments_active_class
                a#comments-tab href="#comments"= t '.tabs.comments'
            li.tabs-title class=other_active_class
              a#other-tab href="#other"= t '.tabs.other'

          .auctions.tabs-content data-tabs-content="customer-auction-tabs"
            #chat.tabs-panel class=chat_active_class
              = render partial: "shared/auctions/chat", locals: { auction: auction }

            #offers.tabs-panel class=offer_active_class
              = render partial: "shared/offers/new", locals: { offer: offer }

            #comments.tabs-panel class=comments_active_class
              = render partial: 'shared/offers/comments', locals: { offer: offer }

            #other.tabs-panel class=other_active_class
              - if auction.offers.count.zero?
                = t "ingen andre bud endnu"
              = render "shared/offers/other"
              .offers= render offers
```

I don't understand how this works because `find_or_create_by` is apparently supposed to work even if the object hasn't been saved.

Can someone help me solve this issue, and preferably avoid using logic like `find_or_create_by` in the view at all?

Here is part of the Offer model:

```
class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  has_paper_trail

  belongs_to :auction, -> { with_deleted }, counter_cache: true, touch: true
  belongs_to :technician, counter_cache: true, foreign_key: :technician_id

  has_one :settings, through: :technician

  has_many :comments, -> { order(created_at: :asc) }, class_name: "OfferComment"

  has_one :review, as: :target
  delegate :rating, to: :review, allow_nil: true
  delegate :rating_date, to: :review, allow_nil: true
  delegate :rating_comment, to: :review, allow_nil: true

  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :cents, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }

  validate :amount_validity

  scope :not_by, ->(technician) { where.not(technician: technician) }
```

Here is also the controller update action that gets called when updating the form with a null field:

```
class Technicians::OffersController < Technicians::ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    render "technicians/auctions/lost", status: 404
  end

  def update
    offer.attributes = offer_params

    changed = offer.changed?

    if offer.save
      OfferUpdatedWorker.perform_async offer.id if changed
      flash[:info] = t(".success")
      redirect_to [:technicians, auction]
    else
      flash.now[:error] = t(".failure")
      render "technicians/auctions/show",
        locals: { auction: auction, offer: offer },
        status: 400
    end
  end
```

Another important file to note is the auction controller that originally calls "technicians/auctions/show"

```
  def show
    render(:lost) && return if lost?

    render :show, locals: {
      offers: sorted_o,
      auction: auction,
      #other: other,      
      offer: offer,
    } if stale? **cache_options(auction.id, auction.updated_at)
  end

  private
#=begin
    def sorted_o
      @sorted_o ||= begin
        field = (%w[cheapest closest guarantee] & [params[:sort]])[0].presence || "cheapest"

        case field
        when "closest"
          auction
            .offers
            .includes(:auction, :technician, :review)
            .sort_by { |o| distance(o.technician, auction) }
        when "guarantee"
          auction
            .offers
            .includes(:auction, :technician, :review)
            .joins(:settings)
            .order("technician_settings.guarantee desc")
        else
          auction
            .offers
            .includes(:auction, :technician, :review)
            .order(cents: :asc)
        end
      end
    end
#=end
    def offer
      @offer ||= auction.offers.by(current_user) ||
        auction.offers.new(technician: current_user)
    end
```

Comment: you really should try moving the code where possible to the controller to streamline your view.  `find_or_create` shouldn't really be in the view

Comment: I know I'm just working with this code at my internship, I would like to move things to the controller eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The cause of the problem was that when the `update` action fails in `offers_controller.rb` it calls the `show` view without the `offers` variable, this variable is somehow related to the `offer_comments`, but I'm not sure how/why because `offer_comments` is supposed to be only related to the variable `offer` and not `offers`.

However, when I checked the console there were null elements in the offer_comments so I just went on and changed the view to only show non null elements, the error stack then pointed to `offers` not being defined in the `show` view.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need `offer_comment` to be saved before a read_receipt that belongs to it can be created, which makes sense - the offer_comment doesn't have an id until it has been saved.

This might get you past the problem.

```
offer_comment.tap(&:save).read_receipts.find_or_create_by user: current_user
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to fix the issue, I still get the same error. However the object offer of class `Offer` is the parent of offer_comment, and I need this view to show even when the updated offer is not saved.